# Alter An Existing Column So It Pulls In Data From Another Table In A MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a MYSQL database (in PHPMyAdmin) with two tables `users` and `posts`. Both have a `username` column. I'd like to modify the `username` column in the `posts` table and make it so it pulls in the username data from `users` table i.e. the data in the `posts` table automatically updates from the `users` table and references it on any updates to the `users` table.

I initially thought this was done using a foreign key, but if I understand correctly foreign keys only relate to primary keys in the parent table?

I'm getting an error message saying the following syntax is incorrect, although it isn't giving me any hints/solutions:

```
ALTER TABLE posts
MODIFY COLUMN username VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL
REFERENCES users(username) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

How do I modify an existing column so that it references/uses the data of a column in a different table in the database?

The `username` column in both tables has the same type, size and attributes, namely `VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL` and is using the innoDB storage engine.

Comment: Look up how to use `JOINS`.

Comment: @danblack aren't `joins` used when you are querying the database? I would like the `posts` table `username` column to be populated from `users` table `username` column in the same way a foreign key column is populated using the primary key of a different table.

Comment: `in the same way a foreign key column is populated using the primary key of a different table` - this isn't a thing. In a Structured Query Language, it's the Query that provides the Structure

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key is a data integrity check, nothing more. It ensures that a field in a child table contains a value that appears in the referenced field in the parent table. That's all <sup>*</sup>.

You can't use a foreign key as some magic to incorporate data from one table into another. However, the `JOIN` statement does exactly what you need, and used in conjunction with a foreign key ensures that every post has a valid username to identify the correct user data.

Take this example:

**User data**

```
CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `displayName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**Posts**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_posts_userdata_idx` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_posts_userdata` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `userdata` (`username`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

We can `JOIN` the `userdata` table to the `posts` table with this query:

```
select 
    `posts`.`id` AS `postId`,
    `posts`.`username` AS `username`,
    `posts`.`message` AS `message`,
    `userdata`.`id` AS `userId`,
    `userdata`.`displayName` AS `displayName`,
    `userdata`.`email` AS `email` 
from (`posts` 
         join `userdata` 
         on(`userdata`.`username` = `posts`.`username`));
```

You can take this one step further and create a `VIEW` that returns data based on this query:

```
CREATE VIEW `posts_users` AS 
  select 
    `posts`.`id` AS `postId`,
    `posts`.`username` AS `username`,
    `posts`.`message` AS `message`,
    `userdata`.`id` AS `userId`,
    `userdata`.`displayName` AS `displayName`,
    `userdata`.`email` AS `email` 
  from (`posts` 
         join `userdata` 
         on(`userdata`.`username` = `posts`.`username`));
```

Use the view with a `SELECT` statement:

```
    select * from posts_users order by postId
```

Demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tbBXvthBtwH7CKu1yjzPjQ/0

<sup>*</sup> Foreign keys also allow updates and deletions to the parent table to cascade to the child, but that's beyond the scope here.

Comment: UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`) is surely redundant

Comment: @radocaw probably, but I just pasted the `CREATE` statement that MySQL Workbench generated. It works and I didn't have time to second guess it